# How can I sum array elements in place in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I create a new array for summing array elements in place in Ruby?

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_cons(2).map {|a, b| a + b }
```

gives me `[3, 5, 7, 9]` but expected result is `[1,3,6,10,15]`.

Comment: ⇑ Welcome, PHP!

Comment: Yes, just old school solution.. :)

Comment: @MuratUstuntas what does "in place" mean?

Comment: @Stefan, i means "in place"  that you should update the original array rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @MuratUstuntas in that case, _"How can i create a **new** array"_ is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Stefan; yes. right the question may be "How can i create a array for summing array elements in place in ruby?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].each_with_object([]){|e, a| a.push(a.last.to_i + e)}
# => [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: `to_i` results in failing on, say, strings.

Comment: `#to_i` is certainly there for the convention that `nil.to_i` returns `0`. Aimed at numbers only.

Comment: @mudasobwa Not sure what you mean. Where does a string come from?

Comment: Although this might solve the problem, it is always good to add an explanation why/how this works.

Comment: @sawa Array might consist of any objects, having `#+` defined on, I don’t see any reason to reject anything save for `Numeric`s. `a.push(a.last ? a.last + e : e)` would work for anything.

Answer (score 8):

More simple for understanding, I think:

```
temp_sum = 0
arr.map! {|e| temp_sum += e }
=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

If you want to create a new array instead of existing one, just use `map` instead of `map!`

Comment: The first answer here so far answering “in place” part of the question. It has a drawback of producing N sums, but it could be fixed with `.with_object(temporary_sum)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, fixed:)

Comment: `arr.each_with_object(sum: 0).map! {|e, acc| acc[:sum] += e }`

Comment: @mudasobwa, this is shining.

Comment: I think your solution should use map instead of map! because author wants new array as a result. 
"How can i create a new array for summing array elements in place in ruby?"

Comment: @SunnyMagadan, usually `in place` means `mutator`. But I'll add your remark.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this. One way is to create an `Enumerator` instance and use `inject`:

```
def adder array
  enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
    array.inject (0) do |sum, n|
      y << sum + n
      sum + n
    end
  end
  enum.take array.size
end

adder [1,2,3,4,5] #=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Comment: `(sum + n).tap &y.method(:<<)`

Comment: @mudasobwa, yes this is great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation:

```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce([]) {|acc, el| acc << el + (acc[-1] || 0); acc}
#=> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Yuk.

Comment: If you use inject/reduce and have to return an object in a second statement inside the block, it means you could probably use each_with_object.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but it seems to work :

```
[1,2,3,4,5].each_with_object([]){|i,l| l<<(l.last||0)+i}
#=> [1,3,6,10,15]
```

Comment: @MuratUstuntas this is insane (besides that this is not a winner, re-examine your benchmarks.) The difference in half of nanosecond should not matter when choosing the proper solution.

Comment: I agree with @mudasobwa : your benchmark basically shows that there'
s no big statistical variations between those implementations. So choose only depending on, say, code readability and familiarity to the used methods.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I just say a word. If i made a mistake, forgive me. :)